# Problem on Linear Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y_1,y_2$ be two solutions of $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$, show that the Wronskian can be expressed as $\displaystyle W(y_1,y_2)=ce^{-\int pdx}$

My thoughts: Wronskian, $\displaystyle W= \begin{vmatrix}
y_1 &y_2 \\ 
y_1' &y_2' 
\end{vmatrix}$

Now, If p, q are given specifically, I can try to find the complementary function (C.F.) and move on from there. But here, p and q are general functions. How do I proceed to solve this problem ?

Any hints ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding out

$W= \begin{vmatrix} y_1 &y_2 \\ y_1' &y_2' \end{vmatrix}, \tag{1}$

we have

$W = y_1y_2' - y_1'y_2, \tag{2}$

whence

$W' = y_1'y_2' + y_1y_2'' - y_1''y_2 - y_1'y_2' = y_1y_2'' - y_1''y_2. \tag{3}$

Now since $y_1$ and $y_2$ satisfy

$y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0, \tag{4}$

then we have

$y_i'' = -p(x)y_i' - q(x)y_i \tag{5}$

for $i = 1, 2$.  Using (5) in (3) we find

$W' = y_1(-p(x)y_2' -q(x)y_2) - (-p(x)y_1' - q(x)y_1)y_2$
$= -p(x)(y_1y_2' - y_1'y_2) =-p(x)W; \tag{6}$

the terms containing $q(x)$ cancel out.  Now observe that

$W(x) = W(x_0)ew^{-\int_{x_0}^x p(s) ds)} \tag{7}$

is the unique solution of (6) satisfying $W = W(x_0)$ at $x = x_0$; this can be verified by direct differentiation of (7); I leave the details to my readers.  We have shown $W(x)$ takes the requisite form with $c = W(x_0)$.  ***QED.***

***Note:***  For more on this and related problems, see here:  [Linear differential equation and its Wronskian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922100/linear-differential-equation-and-its-wronskian).  ***End of Note.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: You are so good at these proofs. WHAT IS YOUR SECRET?

Comment: @usukidoll:  First of all, thanks for the good word; it's nice to be appreciated for one's skills.  As for my "SECRET", it's mostly practice and reading a lot of good mathematical authors.  If you check my user page, you'll see that I am a musician; well, even the ancient philosophers (Plato?) saw the connections 'twixt math and music.  I think both activities are essentially non-verbal, both involve expressing logical structure and patterns, and both require PRACTICE to attain one's highest level of competence.

Comment: @usukidoll:  I've been constructing proofs for a long time, so just like with pickin' the guitar, I improved over time.  I also like working out proofs, so its easy for me to do it while waiting for the train , etc.  In fact, I don't often memorize proofs of important theorems, but try to be ready to derive them at any moment.  So that helps.  If you like creating proofs, and have a knack for it, just KEEP DOING IT!!!  You'll get better and better at it as time goes on.  Well, I couls go on about this forever so I guess I'd better stop now!

Comment: @usukidoll:  there is one more thing:  I like to read a lot, all sorts of stuff--math and science, detective novels, poetry, you name it.  Having strong verbal/reading/writing abilities helps a lot with organizing and expressing ideas.  Writing proofs is, after all, a form of writing . . .

Comment: @usukidoll:  Finally, here's an idea:  someone shpuld offer a class/seminar in creative mathematical writing, where students could work on these skills.  Just a thought.  Cheers!